# Issues using Clisp to compile files

Tags: common-lisp, clisp

So I'm using the new Bash on Ubuntu on Windows shell, and installed the clisp package to mess with Common Lisp. I get this error when I try `clisp test.clisp`:

`/usr/lib/clisp-2.49/base/lisp.run: error while loading shared libraries: libavcall.so.0: cannot enable executable stack as shared object requires: Invalid argument`

This is an entirely fresh install too. I looked in `/usr/lib` and found the `libavcall.so.0` file, but I'm not sure what to do with it. How do I fix this issue?

Comment: "cannot enable executable stack" googling leads to http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/faq.html#CP.19. Maybe that'll help.

Comment: Not an answer, but to start playing around with clisp on Windows, you could also install a [windows build of clisp](https://sourceforge.net/projects/clisp/files/). 
Then, regardless of whether you go for the Ubuntu or Windows version, grab yourself an IDE. I started off with [LispIDE](http://daansystems.com/lispide/), a great, little, free, native Windows app. 
Once I became more comfortable with Lisp, I switched to using emacs+slime as my IDE, and have never looked back. Because it is written "on" Lisp, emacs rapidly became my favorite editor for almost all my text editing requirements.

Comment: Thanks! While I've got no idea how to fix this, I'll be using this.

Comment: It has GitHub issue page about it: https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/1128

Comment: Windows Developer Feedback page: https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/266908-command-prompt-console-bash-on-ubuntu-on-windo/suggestions/17629492-maxima-and-common-lisp-should-work

Answer (score 3):

This issue no longer exists with `libffcall` 2.0 or newer. It was fixed through [this commit](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=libffcall.git;a=commit;h=f08e20fb6a6d3ae630a84dafc0ec7e0c9763ae26).

If you are still using `libffcall` 1.x: The [FAQ](http://www.crypt.gen.nz/selinux/faq.html#CP.19) (cited by user @cybevnm) explains most of it:

- `libavcall.so` is flagged as requiring executable stack (property `GNU_STACK` has the value `RWE`), although it does not need an executable stack. This occurs because it was compiled from assembly-language source code.
- You can remove this flag through a command such as `sudo execstack -c /usr/lib/libavcall.so.0`.

Comment: I removed the flag as suggested, but got the same error but with `libcallback.so.0`. Because it was the same error, I thought it'd be fixed if I just used `sudo execstack -c /usr/lib/libcallback.so.0` again. I get this new error `UNIX error 5 (EIO): I/O error, Unprintable error message` over and over again until I kill the process.

Comment: @BensonChau I don't know for sure, so just guesing, very probably those libraries do require the executable stack flag and your way is to disable the executable call stack protection (for your CL session or system-wide) instead of droping those flags from binaries...

Comment: Right, so I went and reversed those changes by added the flags back onto the binaries. Do you mind if I ask how I should go about disabling executable call stack protection for the CL session? I've honestly no idea how.

Comment: @BensonChau I don't know, probably google can help you